# What is the command to display the days of the year 2016 in UNIX?

Tags: unix

What is the command to display the days of the year 2016 in UNIX ??

[image: Calendar image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question is rather open-ended.  Do you want to display an image, such as the one you've provided, or what, exactly?  If you clarify the business need and indicate what you've done to solve it (and why that didn't work) we may be able to help.  Please revise your question to provide details.  If you need help with understanding how to get help, this should provide assistance: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sanket, you have a couple answers. It'll be great if you can accept one of the answers as accepted. Others who come across your question can benefit by seeing that your question has an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `cal`, you can type `cal 2016` to get all days of the calendar.

Here's how the output looks like:

```
$> cal 2016
                            2016
      January               February               March          
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
                1  2      1  2  3  4  5  6         1  2  3  4  5  
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9   7  8  9 10 11 12 13   6  7  8  9 10 11 12  
10 11 12 13 14 15 16  14 15 16 17 18 19 20  13 14 15 16 17 18 19  
17 18 19 20 21 22 23  21 22 23 24 25 26 27  20 21 22 23 24 25 26  
24 25 26 27 28 29 30  28 29                 27 28 29 30 31        
31                                                                

       April                  May                   June          
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
                1  2   1  2  3  4  5  6  7            1  2  3  4  
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9   8  9 10 11 12 13 14   5  6  7  8  9 10 11  
10 11 12 13 14 15 16  15 16 17 18 19 20 21  12 13 14 15 16 17 18  
17 18 19 20 21 22 23  22 23 24 25 26 27 28  19 20 21 22 23 24 25  
24 25 26 27 28 29 30  29 30 31              26 27 28 29 30        
                                                                  

        July                 August              September        
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
                1  2      1  2  3  4  5  6               1  2  3  
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9   7  8  9 10 11 12 13   4  5  6  7  8  9 10  
10 11 12 13 14 15 16  14 15 16 17 18 19 20  11 12 13 14 15 16 17  
17 18 19 20 21 22 23  21 22 23 24 25 26 27  18 19 20 21 22 23 24  
24 25 26 27 28 29 30  28 29 30 31           25 26 27 28 29 30     
31                                                                

      October               November              December        
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
                   1         1  2  3  4  5               1  2  3  
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8   6  7  8  9 10 11 12   4  5  6  7  8  9 10  
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15  13 14 15 16 17 18 19  11 12 13 14 15 16 17  
16 17 18 19 20 21 22  20 21 22 23 24 25 26  18 19 20 21 22 23 24  
23 24 25 26 27 28 29  27 28 29 30           25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Comment: Try 'cal 1752' and look for September 3rd

Comment: @DavidZimmerman hah, what kind of sorcery is that? I had to find what was going on and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17903 explains the fun. Thanks for pointing this out; I had no idea.

Comment: In a former life, I worked on a unix port and one of the tests for 'cal' verified that Sept 1752 is missing 11 days.

Answer (score 0):

This command:

```sh
cal -j 2016
```

will display the numbers of days for a given month starting with day `1` and end with `365` `(31/12/2016)`